# python GUI to build a simple typing tutor game

Tags: python, user-interface

I've never created a GUI before, just simple text based stuff.  I think I'm ready to move on to building a GUI and I have a project in mind.  Specifically, I'm thinking about creating a simple touch typing tutor game...nothing too fancy.  Which python GUI toolkit and builder would lend itself best to a project like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote several application prototypes using the libglade library and the python bindings.

I found the toolkit pretty easy to use, it acted just like any other GUI widget framework I've used, but the widgets seemed more ready to grow or shrink to fit the available space easier than many other GUI frameworks.

Since they were just prototypes, I can't give you feedback on what it is like to maintain the interface for years -- but they sure went together easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pygame modul
Pygame site has a lot of tutorials, you can use those tutorials as a starting point.

Good Luck!